# TAP Airline Refund

Tags: air-travel, refunds, tap-portugal

I purchased two tickets to Prague in November 2019 to leave June 16, 2020 on Priceline.com with the airline TAP -Then COVID hit. In May 2020 I was told by Priceline that I had to call TAP to reschedule or get a refund/travel credit. I did and they told me I had to wait until the day of my departure. I called and called and called on the day of my departure and none answered. I sent an email, no one answered (and still has not almost a year later). I got on Facebook and contacted TAP they said it's Priceline that needs to refund me - Priceline says its TAP. I want to take the trip again when it's safe, I just want a travel credit and not one person in TAP or Priceline will respond or help. I paid with American Express and they said that since TAP won't respond there is nothing they can do. I'm out over $1000

Comment: Did TAP cancel the flight or did you cancel (or just didn't show up at the airport) ?

Comment: IIRC in May 2020 COVID was on the mend most places, and it looked like a fair possibility it might have cleared up by June.  They may have simply been telling you "hang on and see if this clears up, you might be able to do your itinerary after all".  But it certainly was to their benefit to try to delay you from seeking a refund.

Comment: Did you just call Amex or did you actually raise a dispute using their online service https://www.americanexpress.com/uk/customer-service/dispute-charge.html  I did the latter for a similar situation with a different airline and received a refund within a few days